# How do i array a collection in 3 cols in liquid by a status

Tags: arrays, collections, jekyll, liquid

I wanna array my collection in 3 cols, for 3 different statuses. And if there isn't any gig/item with that status, it has to say ' No projects'

I have tried this:

```
<div class="col-sm">
    <h2>Up next</h2>
    {% assign next = site.gigs | gig.status == 'Next' | sort: gig.date %}
    {% if next.gigs.size == 0 %}
      No projects
    {% else %}
      {% for gig in next %}
        {{ gig.title }}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
</div>
<div class="col-sm">
    <h2>Working on</h2>
    {% assign on = site.gigs | gig.status == 'On' | sort: gig.date %}
    {% if on.gigs.size == 0 %}
      No projects
    {% else %}
      {% for gig in on %}
        {{ gig.title }}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
</div>
<div class="col-sm">
    <h2>Done</h2>
    {% assign done = site.gigs | gig.status == 'Done' | sort: gig.date %}
    {% if done.gigs.size == 0 %}
      No projects
    {% else %}
      {% for gig in done %}
        {{ gig.title }}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

But it just arrays all of the gigs/items :(

Maybe it can be done in a way more simple way.
I don't know if you could make one compact liquid code and array 3 columns by counting the number of different statuses.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

### Ordering

Our statuses are "Next", "On" and "Done". They must be ordered in such order.
As this is not an alphabetical sort order, we need to define this order by ourself.

In **_config.yml** :

```
status-order:
  -
   name: "Next"        ### status as it is set on gigs (!!! Case-Sensitive !!!)
   display: "Up Next"  ### status column header to display
  -
   name: "On"
   display: "Working On"
  -
   name: "Done"
   display: "Done"
```

We can now loop over `site.status-order` and get our gigs in desired status order.

```
{% for status in site.status-order %}
  {{ status.name }} - {{ status.display }}
{% endfor %}
```

### Presenting

As your current code is a little repetitive, we can factor it like this :

```
{% for status in site.status-order %}
  {% assign items = site.gigs | where: 'status', status.name | sort: date %}
  <div class="col-sm">
    <h2>{{ status.display }} ({{ items.size }})</h2>
    {% if items.size > 0 %}
      <ul>
      {% for item in items %}
        <li><a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ item.url }}">{{ item.title }}</a></li>
      {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    {% else %}
      No project
    {% endif %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

### Note

You must be sure to set status with the right case (eg : "Next" an not "next").

And the right type. If you set `status: On` it is understood as the `true` boolean value, not the `string` "on". In this case the correct status expression is `status: "On"`. It must be quoted or double quoted to be understood as "On" string.

Any item with incorrectly cased or typed status expression will not appear in our listing.